# How can I upload a large text that exceeds the limit of 10mb per request to Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I need to upload a large text that contains base 64 encoded images to Firestore but I get this error:

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 11534336 bytes.
    at callErrorFromStatus (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at /Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
for call at
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:160:34)
    at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
    at /Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:227:29
    at /Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
    at repeat (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:80:25)
    at /Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:118:13
    at OngoingCallPromise.call (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)
    at NormalApiCaller.call (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/normalApiCaller.js:34:19)
    at /Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/createApiCall.js:84:30
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Caused by: Error
    at WriteBatch.commit (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:433:23)
    at DocumentReference.set (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:393:27)
    at addDocuments (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/firebase.js:28:57)
    at /Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/app.js:165:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at isLoggedIn (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/app.js:47:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/brunovaranda/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3) {
  code: 3,
  details: 'Request payload size exceeds the limit: 11534336 bytes.',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}

Node.js v18.14.2
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The whole text is being uploaded to a collection named "posts" in Firestore to the "textBody" property of a specific document, is there any way to divide the string into many parts and upload each one at a time and still maintain the integrity of the text keeping it all together in the "textBody" field?

I'm using an express server to send the data and I already changed the request body size limit, so the problem should be exclusively from Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

> The whole text is being uploaded to a collection named "posts" in Firestore to the "textBody" property of a specific document.

There is no way you can add 10 MiB into a single document. This is because the [maximum limit of a document is 1 MiB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits).

> Is there any way to divide the string into many parts and upload each one at a time and still maintain the integrity of the text keeping it all together in the "textBody" field?

In your specific use case, you can divide the file into 10 files and add each file as a separate document in the collection. To put them all together, you have to read all 10 documents in the same order you have added them.

When it comes to larger files, you might also consider using [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage). In this way, you can upload the entire file and read it in one piece. In this case, there is no need to divide it into multiple files.

Comment: Hey Bruno. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?